# having problems understanding a tutorial on one page scroll-vanilla JS- no libraries

Tags: javascript, onepage-scroll

I was looking into one of the only few full page scroll codes which I have found so far, and wanted to somehow get the idea of what I should do by reversing the engineering but I'm noob and not good at understanding it pretty well, I don't understand it well and I get stock at every line, can you please explain to me what the guy has done? Whats the basics of what he is doing ..variables and functions and what they are in this case and why we need them? A summary on what is going on.
this is the link to the code

```
https://codepen.io/igstudio/pen/pbYOab
```

this is the JS code

```
(function() {
    "use strict";
    /*[pan and well CSS scrolls]*/
    var pnls = document.querySelectorAll('.panel').length,
        scdir, hold = false;

function _scrollY(obj) {
    var slength, plength, pan, step = 100,
        vh = window.innerHeight / 100,
        vmin = Math.min(window.innerHeight, window.innerWidth) / 100;
    if ((this !== undefined && this.id === 'well') || (obj !== undefined && obj.id === 'well')) {
        pan = this || obj;
        plength = parseInt(pan.offsetHeight / vh);
    }
    if (pan === undefined) {
        return;
    }
    plength = plength || parseInt(pan.offsetHeight / vmin);
    slength = parseInt(pan.style.transform.replace('translateY(', ''));
    if (scdir === 'up' && Math.abs(slength) < (plength - plength / pnls)) {
        slength = slength - step;
    } else if (scdir === 'down' && slength < 0) {
        slength = slength + step;
    } else if (scdir === 'top') {
        slength = 0;
    }
    if (hold === false) {
        hold = true;
        pan.style.transform = 'translateY(' + slength + 'vh)';
        setTimeout(function() {
            hold = false;
        }, 1000);
    }
    console.log(scdir + ':' + slength + ':' + plength + ':' + (plength - plength / pnls));
}
/*[swipe detection on touchscreen devices]*/
function _swipe(obj) {
    var swdir,
        sX,
        sY,
        dX,
        dY,
        threshold = 100,
        /*[min distance traveled to be considered swipe]*/
        slack = 50,
        /*[max distance allowed at the same time in perpendicular direction]*/
        alT = 500,
        /*[max time allowed to travel that distance]*/
        elT, /*[elapsed time]*/
        stT; /*[start time]*/
    obj.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e) {
        var tchs = e.changedTouches[0];
        swdir = 'none';
        sX = tchs.pageX;
        sY = tchs.pageY;
        stT = new Date().getTime();
        //e.preventDefault();
    }, false);

    obj.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); /*[prevent scrolling when inside DIV]*/
    }, false);

    obj.addEventListener('touchend', function(e) {
        var tchs = e.changedTouches[0];
        dX = tchs.pageX - sX;
        dY = tchs.pageY - sY;
        elT = new Date().getTime() - stT;
        if (elT <= alT) {
            if (Math.abs(dX) >= threshold && Math.abs(dY) <= slack) {
                swdir = (dX < 0) ? 'left' : 'right';
            } else if (Math.abs(dY) >= threshold && Math.abs(dX) <= slack) {
                swdir = (dY < 0) ? 'up' : 'down';
            }
            if (obj.id === 'well') {
                if (swdir === 'up') {
                    scdir = swdir;
                    _scrollY(obj);
                } else if (swdir === 'down' && obj.style.transform !== 'translateY(0)') {
                    scdir = swdir;
                    _scrollY(obj);

                }
                e.stopPropagation();
            }
        }
    }, false);
}
/*[assignments]*/
var well = document.getElementById('well');
well.style.transform = 'translateY(0)';
well.addEventListener('wheel', function(e) {
    if (e.deltaY < 0) {
        scdir = 'down';
    }
    if (e.deltaY > 0) {
        scdir = 'up';
    }
    e.stopPropagation();
});
well.addEventListener('wheel', _scrollY);
_swipe(well);
var tops = document.querySelectorAll('.top');
for (var i = 0; i < tops.length; i++) {
    tops[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        scdir = 'top';
        _scrollY(well);
    });
}
})();
```

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure anyone is going to hold your hand and go through all 100+ lines of this code with you line by line. Do some research and figure it out on your own. If / when you get stuck, come back and ask specific questions and they will get answered.

Comment: Okay, I almost understood most of it, but still have problem understanding these 2 lines >> plength = plength|| parseInt(pan.offsetHeight / vmin);
  slength = parseInt(pan.style.transform.replace('translateY(', ''));           What did he replaced transtaley with? what is he trying to do with replacing here? or why he is calculating the height of pan which is the container of elements based on vmin?